# Docker - correct workflow to redeploy an image

Tags: docker, penetration-testing

I am learning docker and running CoreOS with a number of containers.  The containers are CVE vulnerabilities used for pentesting.  When they are exploited they are usually corrupted or contain malicious files.  From the CLI I stop the container, remove it and run the container again.  This is not too bad, but is there a way to automate this especially if I'm not around to redeploy the image.

What is the suggested workflow to accomplish this?

Can I do this from an api so I can just make a button on site for anyone to redeploy the image?

Thanks

Comment: most proper way is to use 'rolling update' feature of docker swarm service: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/